# Spring jms. How to not cache connection. Failover test

Tags: spring, connection, spring-jms, failover

I need to do some failover test in my app that uses spring JMS. I want to simulate broken TCP connection. Spring framework has two implementations of `ConnectionFactory` interface (`SingleConnectionFactory` and `CachingConnectionFactory`) and both of them cache connection. According to documentation they "... ignore calls to `close()`". So that I cannot debug and close that connection. I also don't have access to tools like wireshark and have no access to physical machine to unplug cable. Is there any way that I can simulate "interrupted connection"?

Answer (score 1):

Call `resetConnection()`.

```
/**
 * Reset the underlying shared Connection, to be reinitialized on next access.
 */
public void resetConnection() {
    synchronized (this.connectionMonitor) {
        if (this.target != null) {
            closeConnection(this.target);
        }
        this.target = null;
        this.connection = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. It works. I even noticed that also destroy() method called on factory do that or closeConnection() inherited from SingleConnectionFactory. Before I did it on connection directly so it was not working. Thanks